# flash 5.5 document class file with 2 buttons

Tags: flash, button

I may be asking this question wrong and searching for it wrong. I am trying to build a simple flash presentation with 3 frames, two buttons on the first frame. 1 goes to frame 2, the 2nd goes to frame 3. I know how to code it on the time line, and can get 1 button to work in the class file (.as file). I can not get 2 buttons to work in the class file. I want the code as simple as possible. here is what I have.

package 
{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

public class Buttontest extends MovieClip
{


    public function Buttontest()
    {
        init();
    }
    private function init():void
    {
        ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtonClicks);
        //ball2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtonClicks);

    }
    private function handleButtonClicks(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
        //gotoAndPlay(3);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test - put a symbol on the stage in Flash Pro, called the instance ball and wrote the following code in the Document Class and it worked.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class ClickTest extends MovieClip {

        public function ClickTest() {
            this.gotoAndStop(1);
            this.ball1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ball1Callback);
            this.ball2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ball2Callback);
        }
        private function ball1Callback(e:Event):void {
            trace("ball 1 clicked");
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        private function ball2Callback(e:Event):void {
            trace("ball 2 clicked");
            this.gotoAndStop(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you named the instance on button on the stage.  Also, you might want to use this.goToAndStop() functions, otherwise it will continue looping through the movie.

Comment: Yes this works for 1 button, but I have a 2nd button on frame 1 that is labeled ball2. When that button is pressed I want it to go to frame 3. I am trying to get simple code in the class file for two buttons, I can make one work but I do not know the syntext to get 2 button to work. Your right I should use goToAndStop().

Comment: Just repeat the process - add another button on the first frame in the .fla.  Then duplicate the code code for the first button.  Fixed it above.

Comment: Works very good Thank you. But my buttons stop working after the 2nd click. I added another button that goes back to frame 1 all works well until the 2nd click going back to frame 1, then the first two buttons don't work until you re-run the debug.

Comment: I re-did the whole presentation, using your code. I added in ball3, frame1 had ball1, frame2 ball2, frame3 ball3. The code works great, but you have to have all buttons Ball1, ball2, ball3 on all 3 frames for it to work right. I think when it comes to separate buttons on separate key frames them maybe time line coding is the right thing.

Comment: Add a layer in the timeline for buttons and have it span the three frames - that way you don't have to duplicate anything and all the buttons are always visible.